# Returning object in Yii Component

Tags: php, object, yii

This is hard to explain for me but I'll do my best.

I am starting to write a CApplicationComponent to get config params from DB.

```
<?php

class parameters extends CApplicationComponent
{
  public $cacheAll = false;
  public $dbConnectionId = null;
  public $applications = array();

  public function __get( $attr )
  {
    if( $this->applications && in_array($attr, $this->applications) )
    {
      if( Yii::app()->$$this->applications[$attr]['id'] )
      {
        //in work...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`public $applications` would be an array like this:

```
$arrray = array (
  'productName' => array (
    'tableName'=>'settings',
    'propertyColumn'=>'parameters',
    'valueColumn'=>'values',
   ),
);
```

Well... the fact is that I need, or mostly want, to get an attribute like this:

```
Yii::app()->parameters->productName->param1
```

I know that Yii implements magic getter and setters for class properties, so I would access `$applications` this way:

```
Yii::app()->parameters->applications
```

So, I am now overriding the `__get` function, to see if the requested value is a key in the array $applications, or else I will delegate it to the Yii's defined one with `parent::__get($attr)`.

If the requested value is a key in the $applications array, then I would have to create an object so I can use the `->` operator, and another magic setter/getter, but I really don't know how yet.

IS there a better way of doing it? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks a lot

Comment: What are you having a problem on exactly? On creating an object?

Comment: the problem is how can I have a syntax like that in a component given the details of the $applications array

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have this in your config file:

```
...

'components' => array(
  'parameters' => array(
    'class' => 'path.to.parameters.php',
    'applications' => array(
      'productName' => array(
        'tableName' => 'settings',
        'property' => 'param1'
      ),
    )
  ),
),

...
```

If you want to have `\Yii::app()->parameters->productName->tableName` return the value `"settings"`. Your application component would then have to override the `__get` magic method to check if `$this->applications` contains the `"productName"` key using `isset()` and return that key's value as an object instead of an array.

The application component would look like this:

```
<?php

namespace Sakanade;

class parameters extends \CApplicationComponent
{
  public $cacheAll = false;
  public $dbConnectionId = null;
  public $applications = array();

  public function __get($attr)
  {
    // If `$attr` is a key in `$this->applications`, return that
    if (is_array($this->applications) && isset($this->applications[$attr])) {
      // Convert to an object
      return (object) $this->applications[$attr];
    }

    // Return the default implementation by CApplicationComponent
    return parent::__get($attr);
  }
}
```

I tested this by putting this in a controller:

```
$tableName = \Yii::app()->parameters->productName->tableName;
print_r($tableName); // prints "settings"
```

Other properties that already exist in the component can be accessed normally:

```
var_dump(\Yii::app()->parameters->cacheAll);       // false
var_dump(\Yii::app()->parameters->dbConnectionId); // null
```

Comment: Thanks, but my idea is to use magic setter and getters in a second level.... supose, `Yii::app()->parameters->productName->product_param1` (this is get), `Yii::app()->parameters->productName->product_param1 = 'something'` (this is set). Since `productName` will be returned by component's msetter/getter, I think I might have to create a model in that instance and return that, and implement magic setters and getters in the created model to actually get/set the parameter in the DB. What you think?

Comment: @Jorge I see, so that's what you meant. Yeah, that would be a good idea. You'd probably have to create another class that implements a `__get` and `__set`. If your data is _readonly_, you could get away with converting the array into an object. I updated this answer as an example.